# How do I calculate the following double integral of an integer power of exponentials?

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am interested in the evaluation of the following integral:

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{il\theta}e^{im\varphi}|a+be^{i\theta}+ce^{i\varphi}|^{2n}d\theta d\varphi
$$

where $l$ and $m$ are integers, $n$ is a non-negative integer and $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive numbers such that $a>b+c$. It describes the interactions between currents on two non-intersecting circles in 2d. I think it can be done by expanding the absolute value part in powers of the exponents but the resulting expression is not particularly nice and I'm keen to find out if there's a nicer way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please show the own effort to solve the integral, for instance for $n$ having the small values $0,1,2,3$. As it is, the problem wants a computation of an integral written in some wide generality, the effort to solve it deserves a better "context".

Comment: Note that it may be written as $$-\oint_C\oint_C z^{l-1}w^{m-1}(a + bz + cw)^{2n}\,dz\,dw$$ where $C$ is the unit circle in the complex plane. Cauchy has a *lot* to say about integrals like this...